# JavaScript function not called from onclick attribute correctly

Tags: jquery

**IMPORTANT!: I have to use onclick attribute. Using Jquery on event listener/handler is not an option in my case. Why? I have a lot of other things in my code that are dependent on the attribute and its manifestation in the code.**

When putting alert in `onclick` attribute it's working as expected and the alert is shown in a popup window and return false prevents the form from being submitted by pressing the button:

```
<script>
    $().ready(function() {
        $('.pretty .prettycheckbox').click(function () {

            var myType = $('.pretty .prettycheckbox').find("input[class^=car-type]:checked").val();

            if (myType == 1) {
                $('#sendButton').attr("onclick", "alert('Direct!'); return false;");
            } 

            if (myType == 2) {
                $('#sendButton').removeAttr("onclick");
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working when calling a function from onclick atttribute like:

```
<script>
    $().ready(function() {
        $('.pretty .prettycheckbox').click(function () {

            var myType = $('.pretty .prettycheckbox').find("input[class^=car-type]:checked").val();

            if (myType == 1) {
                $('#sendButton').attr("onclick", "submitDB(); return false;");
            } 

            if (myType == 2) {
                $('#sendButton').removeAttr("onclick");
            }

        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $().ready(function(){
        function submitDB() {
            alert('From function!');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any idea why?

Why is the function ignored?

Comment: You're using jQuery, use `on` to bind event handlers, don't add event handler attributes.

Comment: @zzzzBov I need to use `onclick` attribute.

Comment: @JimmyHendrikz **Why.** most likely the reason you need to add onclick rather than a normal click event is due to another problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @JimmyHendrikz, given your update, you need to stop relying on the `onclick` attribute because it's buggy and a very poor choice for event management. Use classes and `[data-*]` attributes to preserve state, and leave your event handlers as functions in JS, not as attributes in HTML.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you for your advice, but my question is why the function is ignored. Not why this or that technique is better.

Comment: It's ignored because you actually want to work with the onclick property, not the onclick attribute. The property wants a function.

Comment: If you literally need to add the attribute for some stupid reason, i'm not sure how successful you are going to be at that short of re-creating the element with said attribute.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks for your advice. But I would appreciate the answer why the function is ignored. It's happening in Chrome and Firefox too. Both are the latest versions.

Comment: @JimmyHendrikz The "Why" is extremely important. Is the goal for .outerHTML or .innerHTML of a parent to return the element with the attribute? or is it to bind an event to the element. What you are trying to do may have a solution, but we need to know what exactly you are trying to do, besides adding an onclick attribute. What is the goal of adding said attribute? why do you need to add it this way? You already know it doesn't work the way you are doing it.

Comment: @KevinB I need it to school and I need to do it that way. It has to be via onclick ;(

Comment: that's doesn't tell me why...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you have a big scope problem. onclick attributes can only target functions that are in the global scope. In your case, your function is not in the global scope.

```
<script>
    $().ready(function(){
        function submitDB() {
            alert('From function!');
        }
    });
</script>
```

should be

```
<script>
        function submitDB() {
            alert('From function!');
        }
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZeLXY/

I still don't understand why "school" would try to teach how to add onclick attributes using jquery. There's no reason you would EVER want to add onclick attributes to an element with javascript, much less jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

The long and the short of it is that you're doing it wrong.

If you want to bind an event handler to an element, use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) (or appropriate alias, such as [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click)):

```
$('#sendButton').on('click', function () {
    alert('Direct!');
    return false;
});
```

There's absolutely no reason to use the `onclick` attribute, or to even try to set such attributes dynamically.

To unbind event handlers, use [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off):

```
$('#sendButton').off('click');
```

Comment: @JimmyHendrikz, given your update, you're still doing it wrong. Don't ***ever*** rely on `onclick` or other such event attributes. They're not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (myType == 1) {
    $('#sendButton').on("click", function() {
        alert("clicked"); //sorry forgot to edit the callback in!
    });
} 
if (myType == 2) {
    $('#sendButton').off("click");
}
```

If you HAVE to use onclick, don't use jquery.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good practice. You should bind an event to the element not changing an attribute.

```
$('#sendButton').off("click").on("click", submitDB);
```

I just found the problem -> http://jsfiddle.net/VJSRy/
I.e. if you really want to use this approach which is wrong, you should define your function as global one. I.e.:

```
submitDB = function() {
   alert('From function!');
}
```

I.e. skip the *var* in front of *submitDB*.

Comment: prefixing the attribute with `javascript:` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, but the function submitDB() is not triggered ;(

Comment: *$().ready(function(){* should be *$(document).ready(function(){* isn't it? I.e. are you sure that the ready handler is called. Also check http://jsfiddle.net/VJSRy/ It works there.

Comment: Damn, the form is still triggered and onclick ignored ecen if I use `$(document).ready(function(){` , but thanks anyway. It's so frustrating when I cannot trigger a simple alert function using an onclick. Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: @JimmyHendrikz It is working when we take your code line by line and simply remove the document ready around the function.