# Uncaught ReferenceError: parentsCheck is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to JS, but am trying to create a checkbox that when checked will reveal a div with an id of "second_row", and when unchecked will hide it (unchecked by default). Am I missing some code? Is my syntax incorrect? I could really use some help. Thanks for givin a newbie a hand!

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="under_18" id="under_18" class="check" value="under_18" form="contest_form" onclick="parentsCheck()" />
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>

function parentsCheck()
{
  var check1 = document.getElementById('under_18'),

    if (check1.checked === true) { 
      document.getElementById('second_row').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if (check1.checked === false) { 
      document.getElementById('second_row').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

</script>
```

P.S. Dont know if it matters, but the checkbox is in a table cell.

Comment: You should get into the habit of leaving your browser's Console open (press F12 to see it) and looking in there for errors - it would have shown the syntax error straight away.  Much quicker than asking about it here!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `,` at the end of the `var` statement should be a `;`.

It's causing a `SyntaxError`, causing the JavaScript block to be effectively ignored, so `parentsCheck()` is never defined.

```
var check1 = document.getElementById('under_18');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tYv28/

---

As an aside, `check1.checked` will *always* return a boolean, so you don't need to do the `=== true` and `=== false` comparison; the following will work just fine:

```
function parentsCheck()
{
  var check1 = document.getElementById('under_18');

    if (check1.checked) { 
      document.getElementById('second_row').style.display = 'block';
    } else { 
      document.getElementById('second_row').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, swappin the comma to a semicolon worked perfectly. (love when something that tiny smokes me...) Also, thanks for the tip about check boxes being perma-boolean, that will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

When using event handler attributes, JavaScript [only recognizes functions in the global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623413/javascript-function-not-called-from-onclick-attribute-correctly#answer-18623805). Try defining the event handler in your JavaScript, which also has the benefit of being [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript):

```
var el = document.getElementById('under_18');
el.onclick = parentsCheck; // <---- This
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WE983/1/)

Also, you need to change the `,` into a `;`.

Comment: To be fair, your [initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24210091/1) was very vague about the "weird scoping issues"; JavaScript has very well defined scopes, and event handlers only working if they're in global scope isn't weird at all. As you've corrected that however, I'll give you a +1 to counter the -1.

Comment: @Matt That's my assumption, as to why I got the downvote, as well. I don't understand how someone could equate not being explicit to being wrong. Anyways, thanks for the upvote !